# postgresql make output column upper while applying DISTINCT ON

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find distinct on one column and I want to make output to Upper

```
select
   DISTINCT ON (UPPER(approver_wwid)) approver_wwid ,
   approver_name
from cons_temp
```

I'm using Distinct on because name is ambiguous while wwid can be distinct.

I just want to output value of approver_wwid in upper.

### Sample Data

```
approver_wwid | approver_name
ab123         | Jhon Mark
AB123         | Jhon Mark
ab123         | Mark Jhon
CD123         | Dev Tim
cd123         | Dev Tim
```

### Expected Output

```
approver_wwid | approver_name
AB123         | Jhon Mark
CD123         | Dev Tim
```

Comment: Could you please add example data?

Comment: `distinct on ()` without an `order by` doesn't really make sense. What exactly is your question? Do you get the wrong result? Do you get an error?

Comment: I'm getting correct output, I just want first column in UPPER case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make your first column upper:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT ON (approver_wwid) UPPER(approver_wwid) AS approver_wwid,
   approver_name
FROM cons_temp
```

But note, that it is not under your control which row will be returned. 
In your case it could be 'Mark Jhon' or 'Jhon Mark' for the second column.

Comment: It does not matter which value appear in second row as it is just combinations of first name and last of full name, Thanks